# How to run a simple Java program using terminal command?

Tags: command-line, terminal, java

[image: Image1]

As you can see I'm trying to run a Java program but I need the command which I can write in terminal to run the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine the easiest way would be to press the blue arrow at the top.

If it has to be command line though, try

```
Javac Main.java
```

To compile the source to byte code which will give you a Main.class file, then

```
Java Main
```

To run it. The oracle website has a quick guide [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/unix.html)

Comment: Thanks very much it worked well with me, and thanks for the link, it gave me more rich informations.

Comment: @MohamedAli np, the oracle site has a few useful beginners tutorials.